# How can I generate a tuple of N type T's?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want to be able to write `generate_tuple_type<int, 3>` which would internally have a type alias `type` which would be `std::tuple<int, int, int>` in this case.

Some sample usage:

```
int main()
{
    using gen_tuple_t = generate_tuple_type<int, 3>::type;
    using hand_tuple_t = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
    static_assert( std::is_same<gen_tuple_t, hand_tuple_t>::value, "different types" );
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can also consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. Array supports a so called "tuple protocol" (there are overloads of [`std::get<i>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get), [`tuple_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size) and [`tuple_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_element) for `std::array`), thus can be in many cases a drop-in replacement for a tuple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fairly straightforward recursive formulation:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N, typename... REST>
struct generate_tuple_type
{
 typedef typename generate_tuple_type<T, N-1, T, REST...>::type type;
};

template<typename T, typename... REST>
struct generate_tuple_type<T, 0, REST...>
{
  typedef std::tuple<REST...> type;
};
```

[Live example](https://goo.gl/QekPUY)

[Update]

OK, so I was only thinking about modest values of `N`. The following formulation is more complex, but also significantly faster and less compiler-crushing for large arguments.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename /*LEFT_TUPLE*/, typename /*RIGHT_TUPLE*/>
struct join_tuples
{
};

template<typename... LEFT, typename... RIGHT>
struct join_tuples<std::tuple<LEFT...>, std::tuple<RIGHT...>>
{
  typedef std::tuple<LEFT..., RIGHT...> type;
};

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct generate_tuple_type
{
  typedef typename generate_tuple_type<T, N/2>::type left;
  typedef typename generate_tuple_type<T, N/2 + N%2>::type right;
  typedef typename join_tuples<left, right>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct generate_tuple_type<T, 1>
{
  typedef std::tuple<T> type;
};

template<typename T>
struct generate_tuple_type<T, 0>
{
  typedef std::tuple<> type;
};

int main()
{
  using gen_tuple_t = generate_tuple_type<int, 30000>::type;
  static_assert( std::tuple_size<gen_tuple_t>::value == 30000, "wrong size" );
}
```

[Live example](https://goo.gl/BwCt7f)

This version performs at most 2*log(N)+1 template instantiations, assuming your compiler memoizes them. Proof left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Note that for medium-sized `N` (900ish), the above will break on most compilers.  And long before that it will be a pig to compile.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I've tested this and it seems to break when N > 490 on my compiler. This can be (sort of...) resolved by concatenating the produced template tuples into one tuple a certain number of times before the compiler breaks again.

Comment: This is  exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't managed to make it `log n`, but I knew that concatenating smaller tuples was the way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, each non-leaf of your template tree instantiates 2 children plus a join_tuples.    The two children are identical types unless the parent's N has a 1 ending.  The max radius of the children is thus grows by 1 each recursion, with log(n) recursions (or is there a better guarantee I'm missing?  A limit on the radius?).  So you get log(n) + log(n)-1 + log(n)-2 + ... + 1 max `generate_tuple_type`s, which is `O(log^2(n))`.

Comment: Each non-leaf also calls `join_tuples`, and those are distinct.  I'm not seeing 2*log(N)+1?  More like `2*log^2(N)+1`?  We can bring this down by recursing once, self-`join_tuple`ing, and conditionally appending on the extra element "separately" in another `join_tuples` (or similar).  Not that this matters in practice; log^2(N) is small enough.

Comment: @Yakk: The max radius does not "grow by 1 each recursion"; it is always at most 2 because each level always overlaps completely. Try actually drawing the recursion tree for a few examples until you see the pattern. You are correct that I was not counting the `generate_tuple_type`s, but the overall number of instantiations is still `O(log n)`.

Comment: Ah.  Yes, you are always at `N/2^i` or `N/2^i +1`.  So we get ... up to 3(log(N))+1 distinct types?  With total "symbol length" ... on the order of 2-4 times that, because most of them are short compared to the final output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to give you a pack long enough, and then just wrap it in the type you need. No recursion necessary:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class generate_tuple_type {
    template <typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
    struct impl;

    template <size_t... Is>
    struct impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
        template <size_t >
        using wrap = T;

        using type = std::tuple<wrap<Is>...>;
    };

public:
    using type = typename impl<>::type;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't `std::make_index_sequence<N>` still use recursion?

Comment: @user2296177 it doesn't have to.  It could be compiler magic.  Or, it could use binary tree based recursion, limiting the recursive depth of the factory types used.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [simple one liner](https://godbolt.org/z/v5jaGc48z) with Boost.Mp11.

```
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

int main()
{
    using gen_tuple_t = boost::mp11::mp_repeat_c<std::tuple<int>, 3>;
    using hand_tuple_t = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<gen_tuple_t, hand_tuple_t>, "different types" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the bottom of this link for an example:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence.

You'll need to do a little more work to encapsulate the resulting tuple as a type alias, but the crucial construct here is `std::integer_sequence` and friends.

Comment: Answers on SO should stand on their own. Imagine the target of your link went away; would your answer be usable then?  Include enough in your answer that it stands on its own.