# Function to generate a tuple given a size N and a type T

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, stdtuple

While trying to reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093632/4987285), I found my self in the need of creating a bunch of parameters for a variadic function on the fly where:

- the number of the parameters is not given
- the types are all the same, but unknown (even if they must be default constructible)

At runtime, the *standard containers* and a *for* loop can be used to do that.
Anyway, I'd like to generate a set of parameters at compile time, so as to be able to forward them to a variadic function.
Because of that, a `std::tuple` seemed the obvious solution.

Here arose the question: given a size `N` and a default constructible type `T` at compile time, how can I write a function to generate a tuple of the given size?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
auto tup = gen<MyType, N>();
```

On SO is a [notable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511753/how-can-i-generate-a-tuple-of-n-type-ts) of a recursive generator based structs but I was struggling with a function based solution and I've not been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: If the types are all the same I'd use a `std::array<T, N>` instead of a tuple.

Comment: @davihigh Sure. I ended up using a tuple for it was more challenging indeed. I did it to experiment, nothing more. If I was facing a real problem, I'd have used an `array` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correctly written forwarding function (a la [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)) should work with `std::array<T, N>` and anything else that implements the `std::tuple_size`/`std::get` interface. That said,

```
template<size_t, class T>
using T_ = T;

template<class T, size_t... Is>
auto gen(std::index_sequence<Is...>) { return std::tuple<T_<Is, T>...>{}; }

template<class T, size_t N>
auto gen() { return gen<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

Comment: You made me cry!! :-) ... But at least it was funny to experiment with templates to do such an easy thing in such a complex way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation of such a function:

```
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>

template<typename T>
constexpr auto
params(std::index_sequence<0>) {
    return std::tuple<T>{};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t I, std::size_t... O>
constexpr auto
params(std::index_sequence<I, O...>) {
    auto tup = std::tuple<T>{ T{} };
    auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(O)>{};
    return std::tuple_cat(tup, params<T>(seq));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto
gen(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>) {
    return params<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    auto tup = gen<int>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3>{});
    static_assert(std::tuple_size<decltype(tup)>::value == 3, "!");
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I've used `int` as a type.
With a small effort, user defined types can be used and the constraint of having them default constructible can be relaxed.