# Parameterize of tuple with repeated type

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I want to declare template:

```
template <size_t N, class Type> my_tuple
{
   using type = ... //something here
};
```

So that this `my_typle<3, std::string>::type`,for example, will be the same as this `std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>`
Please, show, how it can be done in one line, maybe, using std::index_sequence or something from boost or whatever? Or maybe it can not be done just simple?

**UPD**

Please, note I do not need an std::array, I need to parametrize some variable template with predefined list of types. I have used std::tuple as an example here.

Comment: Such tuple is spelled `std::array`.

Comment: I need to get the list of types with certain number of elements to parametrize variadic type template with this list.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511753/how-can-i-generate-a-tuple-of-n-type-ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fun. Here's a "pure" meta-programming approach to expand the sequence:

```
template<typename T, typename Seq>
struct expander;

template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct expander<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template<typename E, std::size_t>
    using elem = E;

    using type = std::tuple<elem<T, Is>...>;
};

template <size_t N, class Type>
struct my_tuple
{
   using type = typename expander<Type, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
};
```

I say "pure" ironically. It's more akin to the classic meta-programming tricks, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Use `decltype` with return type of function returning tuple<string,string,...repeated N times>:

```
template<typename T, size_t ... Indices>
auto GetType(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::make_tuple( (Indices,T{})... );
}

template <size_t N, class Type> class my_tuple
{
   using type = decltype(GetType<Type>(std::make_index_sequence<N>())); //something here
};


template<class T>
struct Dummy;

int main(){
    Dummy<my_tuple<3,std::string>::type> d;
```

error on `d` gives you `tuple<string,string,string>`, so it is your desired type.

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
template <typename...>
struct cat_tuple_type;
template <typename... T1, typename... T2>
struct cat_tuple_type<std::tuple<T1...>, std::tuple<T2...>>
{
   using type = std::tuple<T1..., T2...>;
};

template <size_t N, class Type> struct my_tuple
{
   static_assert(N>0);
   using type = typename cat_tuple_type<std::tuple<Type>, typename my_tuple<N-1, Type>::type>::type;
};
template <class Type> struct my_tuple <1, Type>
{
   using type = std::tuple<Type>;
};
```

Then `my_typle<3, std::string>::type` gives the type `std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>`.